# Heroku crash report: State changed from starting to crashed

Tags: heroku, deployment

I'm trying to get to know Heroku deployment. While I try to deploy a test app built in Nodejs with mongoDb, it reports crashed with the following three lines. I don't really understand what exactly causes this error. Appreciate helps please!

> 2019-10-11T16:59:25.802308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fitnessworkoutapp.herokuapp.com request_id=11cb4fff-97e4-41d1-aa55-8b5790fe0384 fwd="84.238.97.184" dyno= connect= se84.238.97.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2019-10-11T17:01:41.121424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fitnessworkoutapp.herokuapp.com request_id=56afd79e-a559-4da6-ada9-1dafec80b3c6 fwd="84.238.97.184" dyno= connect= se84.238.97.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2019-10-11T17:04:02.387025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fitnessworkoutapp.herokuapp.com request_id=25097e7e-6349-4bb7-85a9-89408405a5ee fwd="84.238.97.184" dyno= connect= se84.238.97.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Are you using Procfile ? If yes please share your code.

Comment: @svikramjeet yes i do. It is defined like this: web: node ./bin/www

Comment: Check if this can help you

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys